# Use Python to find average of some numbers

Tags: python, while-loop, except

I am using Python to do a question like keep asking user to enter a number or not. If not,the program should calculate the average of these numbers. It's seems like my program cannot escape from the second while loop, and "except" is still wrong. Here is my program:

```
count =0
total=0
ask=input ("Do you want to enter a number? (Y/N)")
while ask=="Y":
    numbers=float(input("Enter number"))
    count= count+1
    total=total+numbers
    con_ask=input ("Do you want to continue entering a number? (Y/N)")
    if con_ask=="Y":
        numbers=float(input("Enter number"))
        count=count+1
        total=total+numbers
    elif con_ask=="N":
        print ("The average of", count, "numbers is", total/count)
except :
    print ("Zero Division Occured. Average cannot be calculated")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version of computing average number:

```
count = 0
total = 0
ask = raw_input("Do you want to enter a number? (Y/N)")
try:
    while ask == "Y":
        numbers = float(raw_input("Enter number"))
        count = count + 1
        total = total + numbers
        con_ask = raw_input("Do you want to continue entering a number? (Y/N)")
        if con_ask == "Y":
            continue
        elif con_ask == "N":
            print "The average of", count, "numbers is", total / count
            break
except:
    print "Zero Division Occured. Average cannot be calculated"
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
numbers = []
ask = raw_input("Do you want to enter a number? (Y/N) ")
while ask == "Y":
   numbers.append(float(raw_input("Enter number ")))
   ask = raw_input("Do you want to continue entering a number? (Y/N) ")

if numbers:
    avg = sum(numbers,0.0) / len(numbers)
    print "The average of {0} numbers is {1}".format(len(numbers),avg)
else:
    print "You didn't enter any numbers"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to loop while `ask == "Y"`, but later on set the variable `con_ask`.
Could you reuse `ask`?

Also, another way to achieve this could be to first populate an array with all numbers from the input, and then the average becomes:

```
sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Comment: After the second "Y" input the program just keep asking me to enter number. But I want it ask me "Do you want to continue" at every time before I enter in a number.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `while` loop here. You could reuse `ask` so it is tested after each loop iteration.

```
ask=input ("Do you want to continue entering a number? (Y/N)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple program for calculating the average of some number, you might check out the [Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440625/).

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv

t=0
c=0
ans=raw_input("Enetr the choice")

while ans=="Y" or ans=="y":
    a=float(raw_input("Value\t"))
    t=t+a
    c=c+1
    print  "-------------------------------------------"
    print "avarage %f\n" %(t/c)
    ask=raw_input("do you wanna continue \t")
    if ask=="y" or ask=="y":
        continue
    else:
        print "Not wanna more inputs\n"
        break
        print "---------- END ----------------------------"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know how much numbers do you need to enter

My answer is:

```
l=[]

a=int(input('How much numbers you need to enter:'))

for x in range(a):

    s=float(input())
    l.append(s)
print(sum(l)/a)
```

if you don't know how much numbers do you need to enter

```
l=[]

a=input('If you want to enter a number then enter a Y if you dont't enter N:')

while a=='Y':
     s=float(input())
     l.append(s)
     a=input('If you want to enter a number then enter a Y if you dont't enter N:')
print(sum(l)/len(l))
```